# Query execution with time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run sp_WhoIsActive on the query screen once every 5 seconds.

```
   Exec sp_WhoIsActive
   WAITFOR TIME '00:00:05';
```

But i am unable to enter into loop. How can I do that?

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while 1=1
begin
Exec sp_WhoIsActive 
WAITFOR delay'00:00:05'; 
end
```

If you want to clear SSMS pane after results,that's not possible with TSQL..

One option i could think of is to use SSMS Standard reports.

1.Create an .Rdl file with query you need
2.Add that file to custom reports

Below link will guide you in how to part

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/object/add-a-custom-report-to-management-studio

Comment: I tried that, but the result screen is not clearing. Showing over and over.

Comment: are you saying,you want to clear the results after each execution and show only latest one

Comment: check [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/01/sql-server-discard-results-after-query-execution-ssms/) for clearing results

Comment: @Pream:that won't even show results even once,it just discards